# Simplifying a packaged task for a threadpool implementation

Tags: c++, variadic

I wrote a thread pool where the user can submit jobs through `ThreadTask` objects. These objects bundle the job priority, the task as a function, and some arbitrary number of function parameters.

After much frustration I ended up with something like this:

```
struct ThreadTask
{
    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    ThreadTask(exrFloat priority, Func&& func, Args&&... args)
    {
        // package task function with its arguments
        auto pTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<void()>>(std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        // convert packaged task to a void std::function
        m_Task = ([pTask]() { (*pTask)(); });
        m_Priority = priority;
    };

    ...
    std::function<void()> m_Task;
};

...

m_Task();
```

This allows the user to schedule jobs like this:

```
threadPool.ScheduleTask(priority, [&](int customParam1, int customParam2)
{
    ...
}, param1Val, param2Val);
```

This was the only way I knew how to package variadic parameters with the function itself. It works, but looks really ugly. Is there some way I could simplify this?

Comment: Why not just consume a packaged task directly, and let the client figure out how to make it? Then you're just storing objects with a very minimal interface and calling them later. Additionally, why is the task a shared pointer?